# Are "sympathetic nerves" the same as "cardiopulmonary splanchnic" nerves?

Tags: neuroscience, human-anatomy, terminology, autonomic-nervous-system

I've gathered from a number of sources (e.g., [Patel (2015)](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/3-s2.0-B978012410390000038X-f36-04-9780124103900.jpg), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splanchnic_nerves), and [here](https://www.medicinebau.com/uploads/7/9/0/4/79048958/27-sympathetic_nervous_system.pdf)) that the sympathetic nerves leaving the sympathetic trunk to innervate the heart and lungs are called "**cardiopulmonary splanchnic nerves**".

However, I've noticed that both the 14th and 15th edition of Tortora & Derrickson's A&P textbook seem to suggest that these nerves are simply called "**sympathetic nerves**," even though they make reference to abdominopelvic and adrenal splanchnic nerves more specifically.  See below from Tortora & Derrickson (2013):

> ...Then, the axons of the postganglionic neurons leave the trunk by forming **sympathetic nerves** that extend to visceral effectors in the thoracic cavity (Figure 15.4). Sympathetic nerves provide sympathetic innervation to the heart and lungs.

Here are subsets of images from Patel (2015) [LEFT] vs Tortora & Derrickson (2013) [RIGHT] (my emphasis):

[image]

**My question: Are "Sympathetic nerves" the same as "cardiopulmonary splanchnic" nerves?**

- Are these names interchangeable? I can't find further evidence supporting Tortora and Derrickson's usage of this phrase in such a specific manner to refer to postganglionic neurons leaving the trunk to innervate the heart and lungs. Are they acting rogue? Are they simplifying? Any insight would be appreciated.

---

Cited works:

<sup>Patel, T. R. 2015. "Chapter 36 - Anatomy of the Sympathetic Nervous System." Pages 495-506 *in* Tubbs, R.S., Rizk, E., Shoja, M.M., Loukas, M., Barbaro, N. and Spinner, R.J. eds. *Nerves and Nerve Injuries: Vol 1: History, Embryology, Anatomy, Imaging, and Diagnostics*. Academic Press.</sup>

<sup>Tortora, G. J. and B. Derrickson. 2013. Principles of anatomy and physiology, 14th edition. John Wiley & sons, Inc.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You might consider cross-posting to SE Medical sciences who know more about this stuff.

I think that they are simply using a more general term than other authors. In the same way, most people call crabs crabs, but some people might occasionally refer to them as crustaceans.

Based on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympathetic_nervous_system), it seems that cardiopulmonary splanchnic nerves are a subset of sympathetic nerves. The sympathetic nervous system innervates a large number of organ systems of the body (see image), such that the cardiopulmonary splanchnic nerves are simply the sympathetic nerves that innervate the heart and lungs.

Looking further at [the wikipedia for splanchnic nerves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splanchnic_nerves), it seems that this is a technical term relating to the fashion in which organs are innervated by the sympathetic nervous system; e.g. in my crude understanding they are organ hookups to the sympathetic nervous system.

In other words, all cardiopulmonary splanchnic nerves are sympathetic nerves, but most sympathetic nerves are not cardiopulmonary splanchnic nerves.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, -1 b/c I feel like it doesn't answer my question. I know what the sympathetic nervous system is, and I know that the cardiopulmonary splanchnic nerves are the part of the sympathetic system that go to the heart/lungs. I also know that all nerves carrying sympathetic signals are considered "sympathetic nerves". I indicated all of this *in* my post. It appears to me, that *everything* you've mentioned in this answer repeats points made in my question, so I don't think this is actually an answer to my question. Could you clarify your post if this isn't the case?

Comment: IMO you did not indicate all of that. It was not clear that you understood that the sympathetic nervous system could be a superset of nerves of which splanchnic nerves was a subset, and that the authors in question could be substituting a more general term. I am happy to delete the answer if you do not feel that it addresses your question. But if you knew all of that in the first place I am not sure why you are even asking the question? It seems you have answered it yourself before even posting it.

Answer (score -2):

Cardiopulmonary splanchic nerves consist of:

- sympathetic nerves
- the vagus nerve (a part of parasymathetic system)